# HKDF: Difference between salt and info

Tags: hkdf

I want to do generate individual AES keys for a number of smart cards, based on a random master key (key diversification) and the serial number of the card.

According to the answers to [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/6319/pbkdf2-for-key-diversification) HKDF is the/one way to go.

HKDF has three inputs, `ikm`, `salt` and `info`. Feeding in the serial number as part of `ikm` seems to be incorrect usage (and maybe dangerous because it makes the IKM less random?). That leaves `salt` and `info`, which one should I use?

Comment: I don't want to copy and paste for an answer, see section at 3.2 [rfc5869](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5869)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HKDF: ikm, salt and info values](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/64150/hkdf-ikm-salt-and-info-values)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't even understand if these links argue in favor of "salt" or in favor of "info".

Comment: From RFC5869: We stress, however, that the use of salt adds significantly to the **strength** of HKDF. In particular, info **may** prevent the derivation of the same keying material for different contexts.

Comment: @kelalaka I should use `salt` because different `info` might not lead to different output keys, is that what you mean?

Comment: It is what the RFC5869 says.

Comment: @AndreKR: No, it means the `info` parameter may be _used_ to prevent the derivation of the same keying material for different contexts, by making sure that each key derived from the same IKM is derived with a different `info`.

Comment: @kelalaka The same can be said about the salt because of the pigeonhole principle and the RFC does not say the likeliness of a collision is higher for the info. Especially section 3.3 gives the impression (kind of contradicting section 3.1) that an empty salt really is ok if the IKM is uniformly random.

Answer (score 3):

If all you're using HKDF for is deriving subkeys from a uniformly random master key, you [don't really need the Extract part of HKDF.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5869#section-3.3)  So you can simply use your master key directly as the `IKM` input to HKDF-Expand, and the serial number (plus [possibly other identifying information](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/6553/what-information-to-include-is-the-info-input-for-hkdf), if you e.g. may need to derive multiple keys per card) as the `info` input.